# Linking Image control and FileUpload control

Tags: c#

As the heading suggests, I'm trying to give the user the option to choose an image using the **FileUpload** control and after hitting the update button, display it in the **Image** control, existing inside a **Panel** control.

So far I've gotten here. This is my form.

[image: Code 1]

And this is my code.

[image: Code 2]

I let the highlighted code stay inside PageLoad function just for testing. I know it should be inside the Button's event handler.

Also, can someone explain me **why** the above fails to display the image even after hardcoding an absolute URL for **Image.ImageUrl** property. It worked when I referenced it just by giving the file name **cake.png** and putting the file inside the website folder. But I want to reference absolute URLs.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So this is a webforms project?

Comment: [You should avoid using images for code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Could you check your output window in Visual studio as to why you get the error? or just check in your browser as to what the issue is.

Comment: @mahlatse yes. It is a webforms project. And Im not getting an error. Its just that the image does not get displayed when I use absolute URL.

Comment: @Oram Thanks I'll keep that in mind

Comment: Press F12 in your browser and check console for error, this will give you a better idea as to why your image is not showing

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a web application, which can be available on internet and can be accessible throughout the globe. In your example, which is not working, you are referencing a image file from local file system from your own computer, inside a web application. Your Web application is running under its own process and under its own account/user(IUSR in case of IIS) and your local system is running under a different process. so the two can't talk to each other like that.